# how can i get the user_id from jwt in the localstorage and use it in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I am writing a logic to create a post and i want to add the logged in user as the user making the post, i have saved the `refresh`  token in my browser localstorage, when i copy the refresh token and paste in jwt.io, i get this response

```
{
  "token_type": "refresh",
  "exp": 1679234275085,
  "iat": 1674953425085,
  "jti": "d723e65f9bdctret41399e5d09278ef1fcbc",
  "user_id": 1,
  "username": "destiny",
  "email": "desphixs111@mailnator.123"
}
```

now how do i grab the user_id and use it in react, this is where i want to use it

```
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append("user", 1)
```

Instead of hardcoding the user_id as 1 or 2, i want to pass it in dynamically, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you not sending `user_id` within formData, it should be handled by the server to avoid security issue.